# pandas CSV file read won't convert data types from object to int

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, dtype

I am trying to convert my data imported through a CSV file to float or int types due to errors in graphing the data (using plt plot). I have tried almost everything I have seen online, pd.to_numeric, .astype(), creating functions to convert, and every time I receive the error that the code could not convert the string as float. So far all of my dtypes are objects, even the numeric ones. Below is my code:

```
    apo2data = pd.read_csv('/Users/lily/Desktop/Apo2excel.csv')
    type(apo2data)
    apo2data.dtypes
    data = apo2data.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(" ")
    data.info()
    data.head()


    Out[:] <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    RangeIndex: 6676 entries, 0 to 6675
    Data columns (total 38 columns):
    #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype 
   ---  ------       --------------  ----- 
   0   KIC          6676 non-null   object
   1   2MASS        6676 non-null   object
   2   Teff         6676 non-null   object
   3   e_Teff       6676 non-null   object
   4   FeH          6676 non-null   object
   5   e_FeH        6676 non-null   object
   ...
   dtypes: object(38)
   memory usage: 1.9+ MB
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `fillna(' ')`. By doing so, you have columns with mixed-type values. And mixed-type values are always `object` type in Pandas. You can remove `fillna` and you would get `float64` dtypes:

```
data = apo2data.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use 'dtype' parameter to set the correct type, you can find an example on https://honingds.com/blog/pandas-read_csv/

Answer (score 1):

I think you have objects because you forced the to_numeric conversion, so the strings were converted to `NaN`, then you filled `NaN` with `" "`.  If you're sure that all of your columns should be converted to numeric types, I suggest doing some pre-processing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list('12345'),
                   'col2':['green','blue','red','yellow','pink'],
                   'col3':['1 green','2 blue','3 red','4 yellow','5 pink']})
df['col3'] = df.col3.apply(lambda x: x.split()[0]).astype(int)
```